# SharePoint 2010 - SharePoint Timer Service (OWSTimer.exe) crashes every 15 minutes

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, timer-service

I've got a SharePoint 2010 environment.
For some unknown reason the SharePoint Timer service keeps crashing. My Event viewer shows the following event:

```
Fault bucket , type 0
Event Name: CLR20r3
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: owstimer.exe
P2: 14.0.6120.5000
P3: 4f7bb611
P4: System
P5: 2.0.0.0
P6: 4ef6caea
P7: 1b38
P8: 72
P9: System.UriFormatException
P10: 

Attached files:

These files may be available here:
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_owstimer.exe_1b1232bb605b52c873b8d0cef2c733afcd409686_23f35573

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 22a803f8-e07f-11e1-955f-e83935ba4ea4
Report Status: 4

Log Name: Application
Source: Windows Error Reporting
Event ID: 1001
```

I've already spent hours searching online for a solution, but to no avail.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Can you check the ULS logs and see whats happening there ?

Comment: It can be helpful to find out what was changed in time before the first crash.

Comment: @MossFarmer - The frustrating thing is that there are nog relevant entries recorded in the ULS Logs. The Report ID does not turn up when i search for it. Is it possible for me to fine tune the logging to catch more ?

Comment: @IAfanasov - This is a new SharePoint 2010 installation. The day these events started showing up I configured SharePoint Server Search, installed SharePoint Designer 2010 and added a Warmup solution. The Warmup solution i'm using might be the culprit since it runs every 15 minutes (queue dramatic music). I've set the runtime of the warmup script to 30 minutes to see if the owstimer.exe will crash every 30 minutes.

Comment: You can enable diagnostic logging through SharePoint Central Administration and check once again. Its highly improbable that a timer service crash wont be logged in ULS.

Comment: @IAfanasov - Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! It turns out that the Warmup solution i installed was causing the SharePoint Timer Service to crash. Firstly I configured it to run every 30 minutes to see if there was a connection. After seeing that the SharePoint Timer Service then crashed every 30 minutes aswell I disabled the Warmup solution. Now my SharePoint Timer service does not crash anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution in this situation: Check the custom timer jobs.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this.
I had this problem where the SharePoint Timer Service was crashing every 20 mins, and then all SharePoint timer jobs would crash.
To work around this i had to kill the PID ID for the sptimerv4 service.

When I first installed SHarepoint 2010 Standard, i found that a warmup was required. I downloaded a Sharepoint specific one and this is what has been causing the problem.
I have now disabled it and everything running fine.
Took me ages to get here.